# Autoencoder implementation using ImageDataGenerator

Tags: keras, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm using the concept demonstrated in [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/10/7/2511). Their training data consists of "GOOD" images and "BAD" images. They train the AE using "BAD" images (X) to make it produce "GOOD" image. "BAD" images in this case maybe very similar to "GOOD" image but with small dent or scratch.

I've had success using `ImageDataGenerator` on [mnist](https://github.com/sdg002/MNISTpng) number data but in such case it is trained by using `X -> X` or if not using `ImageDataGenerator` the model fitting code will be something like `model.fit(x_train, x_train)`.

However, in this AE problem, we want to train using `X_good_and_defect -> X_good` or  `model.fit(x_good_and_defect_train, x_good_train)`. Not sure how to achieve this using `ImageDataGenerator`.

---

I'm using keras's image data generator to load the images.

```
train_dir = r'chunks/training'
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, target_size=(256,256), 
                   color_mode='grayscale', class_mode='input', batch_size=256)
...
autoencoder.fit(train_generator,
                epochs=5,
                batch_size=128,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(test_generator, train_generator),
                callbacks=[])
```

Answer (score 1):

As the following image from the paper shows, during training time you create patches from larger images. These patches have no defects and can therefore be seen as 'good' images. To get the accompanying 'bad' images with defects you synthetically generate these defects on the 'good' images.

[image]

Your data generator should therefore follow the following steps:

1. Read in full size 'good' images
2. Create patches from the full size images
3. Synthetically add defects to the patches from step 2
4. Return both the 'good' patches from step 2 and 'bad' patches from step 3

You then train your model using the 'bad' patches as the input and your 'good' patches as the output.

Comment: I understand, I'm having difficulty with the part "You then train your model using the 'bad' patches as the input and your 'good' patches as the output." using the train_generator though. Just not sure how.

Comment: I see, I think you'd need to write a custom data generator that returns both the 'bad' and 'good' patches as `ImageDataGenerator` assumes that your data is an image and a label instead of an image and another image. I've personally found [this website](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) to be quite good.